# prop can not be read because object is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am currently trying to understand why after I have created a new object in my notes and questions arrays they are saved to the database but looking at redux their respective states are null after creation and being saved. My issue is because they are null I can not redirect back to the parent graph  for both questions and notes to display the graph and all of its corresponding notes and graphs. Below is my action using thunk to add notes and questions and reducer at some point after the new notes and questions are created they are saved to the database but are still null in state at this point so I can not redirect as needed to view them.

[image: Null State]

```js
Error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'graph_id' of undefined
(anonymous function)
src/containers/Show.js:27
  24 |     console.log(this)
  25 | // variables for objects
  26 | const graph = this.props.graphs.find(graph => { return graph.id === parseInt(this.props.match.params.id)})
> 27 | const notes = this.props.notes.filter(note => note.graph_id === graph.id)
     | ^  28 | const questions = this.props.questions.filter(question => question.graph_id === graph.id)
  29 | 
  30 |
```

```js
Add Actions for both Notes and Questions

export const addNote = (note) => {

    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({type: 'START_ADDING_ADDNOTE_REQUEST'})

        let dispatchData = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(note)
        }
        // fetch made to nested url to create relationship with note and the correct graph
        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/graphs/${note.graph_id}/notes`, dispatchData)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(note => {
        // may be bad practice and need to be refactored as I am mutating the object to work with reducer
            let changedNote = {
                id: parseInt(note.id),
                content: note.content,
                graph_id: note.graph_id
            }
        // dispatches action and objecgt to reducer to add it to state
        dispatch({type: 'ADD_NOTE', changedNote})
        })

        .catch(function(error) {
            alert("ERROR!")
            console.log(error.message)
        })
    }
}


export function  addQuestion(question) {

    return dispatch => {
        dispatch({ type: 'START_ADDING_ADDQUESTION_REQUEST'})

        let dispatchData = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(question)
        }

        fetch(`http://localhost:3001/graphs/${question.graph_id}/questions`, dispatchData)
        .then(function(response) {
            return response.json()
        })
        .then(question => {
            let changedQuestion = {
                id: parseInt(question.id),
                content: question.content,
                graph_id: question.graph_id
            }
            dispatch ({type: 'ADD_QUESTION', changedQuestion})
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            alert("ERROR!")
            console.log(error.message)
        })
    }
}
```

```js
//Questions Reducer
export default function questionsReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    // fetch request to grab questions when graphs loaded  to dashboard
    case 'START_FETCH_QUESTIONS_REQUEST':
        return state
    // add results to array
    case 'FETCH_QUESTIONS':
        return[...state, ...action.questions]


    // add question to database
    case 'START_ADDING_ADDQUESTION_REQUEST':
        return state
        // add new question to state.questions
    case 'ADD_QUESTION':
        return [...state, action.mutateQuestion]
   }
}
```

```js
//Notes Reducer
export default function notesReducer(state = [], action) {
    switch(action.type) {
    // fetch request to grab notes when graphs loaded  to dashboard
    case 'START_FETCH_NOTES_REQUEST':
        return state
    // add results to array
    case 'FETCH_NOTES':
        return[...state, ...action.notes]


    // add note to database
    case 'START_ADDING_ADDNOTE_REQUEST':
        return state
        // add new note to state.notes
    case 'ADD_NOTE':
        return [...state, action.mutateNote]
   }
}
```

Comment: what is inside `this.props.notes`?

Comment: My notes props will have the content the id of that note and the graph_id all that is fine because it gets saved to the database prior to this error. The issue is after its saved I have a button that you click to view all notes and questions to that graph. It is at that point or possibly earlier that the value of the notes and questions is null in state. But if I refresh the page and go directly to the graph to view tis notes and questions the new ones are there because they were added. The act of adding to the graphs seems to create a null state at some point and I am not sure why.